# Best practice for Kafka and Debezium in a CDC Oracle usage

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

We are struggling to find some "best practice" regarding an usage of Kafka/Connect for CDC. What we are trying to achieve;
Extract online redo logs from Oracle through Kafka Connect.
We have ~700 different tables with between a couples of rows to ~40M rows for the biggest tables.

What we thought to use:

- 1 Debezium Oracle CDC
- 1 Kafka Connect
- 1 Kafka
- 1 Schema registry

What's the better approach; 1 connector per table ? meaning we will end up with 700 connectors ? (+700 for the related DDL in "database.server.name" ?)

because if we keep only 1 connector for all tables, the issue is that it will not be parallelised.

I tried to add 3 kafka workers or 3 kafka connect but the issue is still the same, I have only 1 table being processed at the same time.

Any best practice or return of experience will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: I highly doubt that you will need every single table, do you?

Comment: No indeed, 700 first tables are only used for the first step. the total of tables is 40k+ tables, but we will not need all of them. 700 for the first Iteration and we should end up with ~5k tables at the end.

Comment: Keep in mind that Kafka Streams can join streams and tables itself, so I'd suggest you denormalize the data. But to answer the question - yes, you need one connector task per white-listed table

Comment: Okay, Thanks. And to ensure I got it right : - if I want to increase the throughput, I need to add "kafka connect worker", so the task of the kafka connectors will be distributed between them. And if I want to have fault tolerance, I need to add both more kafka connect workers and kafka nodes. Is that correct?

Comment: Multiple brokers for fault tolerance, multiple workers for throughput beyond `tasks.max` setting in any connector, that's right